# pagination with Zend Paginator showing previous, first, last, next, current & current +/- 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

i'm trying to put together pagination for my page using Zend Paginator.
i followed this exmaple (by Lee Davis): http://www.duckheads.co.uk/zend-paginator-example/265

what i expect is more less described in requirements on that page:

```
Must be able to jump to the first results page at any time by clicking the first page number (1)
Must be able to jump to the last results page at any time by clicking the last page number
Must be able to jump forward one page
Must be able to jump back one page
Must show the current page the user is on
Must show surrounding pages from the page the user is currently on
```

I implemented the pagination as per the article mentioned however it does not work exactly as i expected from the screenshot. e.g. it shows more than 1 surrounding page on each side of current page.

Screenshot from the article: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihrIt.jpg

I'm calling the paginationControl method with 'Sliding' parameter.

I wonder if you might know of any modification to example code (from the article) that could make it work the as expected i.e. with changed the last requirement to

```
Must show 1 surrounding page on each side of the page the user is currently on
```

thank you in advance for nudging me the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the doc, I think that tremely set your Zend_Paginator if you add:

```
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator(...);
$paginator->setPageRange(3);
```

it should work. 

Keep me informed. :)